# Почему список изменяется?

Tags: python

как известно, списки в пайтоне передаются по ссылке, что не дает адекватно их передавать в функции.

```
def minor(n, array):
   array.pop(0)
   for item in array:
      item.pop(n)

   return array

a = [[1, 2, 9],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

с = minor(1, a)
```

Список "а" изменяется. Я пробовал передавать список таким образом `с = minor(1, a[:])`, в таком случае

`array.pop(0)` - не работает,

но

```
for item in array: 
     item.pop(n)
```

по какой-то причине все равно изменяет входящий список "а"

Как это исправить?

Comment: Вы хотите то что? Чтобы список списков НЕ менялся этой функцией? Передавайте в нее deepcopy(a), взять эту функцию можно через from copy import deepcopy

Comment: Да, исходный список не должен меняться. Странно что для этого нет каких-то встроенных решений. Спасибо

Comment: Ну, `copy` - это вполне стандартная библиотека

Comment: Только не передавайте копию, а пусть метод minor делает у себя копию. А еще лучше - вообще не делать такую копию и потом "доводить до ума", а парой циклов сразу создавать результат не трогая оригинал.